# Создании Image, исключения типа "System.InvalidOperationException"

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

При создании Image, при выходе из Dispatcher все параметры Image выдают исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException".

```
public Image makeImage(Image img, Dispatcher disp) 
    {
        disp.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {                
                img = new Image();
                MainWindow.Foogrid.Children.Add(img);
                img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                img.Margin = new Thickness(posX, posY, 0, 0);
                SetSkin(_EntImage, img);
        })).Wait();
        return img;
    }
```

В Dispatcher все создается,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при return, когда Dispatcher закончил, все ужас.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду весьма признателен за помощь.

Comment: Ошибку текстом приведите.

Comment: Например img.source, Source "img.Source" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" System.Windows.Media.ImageSource {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Нет, я про полный стек трейс.

Comment: ошибка у меня вылазит позже, когда я пытаюсь использовать этот image, вот что вылазит

Comment: StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at StarPiksIO.Unit.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ChangePosition>b__0() in C:\Users\skrip\Desktop\StarPiksIO\StarPiksIO\Entities\Unit.cs:line 35
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeDelegateCore()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()

Comment: какого результата вы хотите достичь? Ваш код выглядит совсем неправильно для меня.

Comment: Попытаюсь обрисовать ситуацию мега кратко.
Я получаю от сервера сериализованный Dictionary<string, Unit>, в клиенте его десириализую и пытаюсь создать по данным из этого Dictionary картинке, приведенный код, по идее, должен способствовать этому, но нет.

Comment: Чего-то логика не понятна. У вас метод возвращает `Image` и одновременно принимает в качестве параметра, и при этом вы пытаетесь отобразить картинку с помощью работы в диспетчере, а потом присвоенное значение в диспетчере отдать в качестве результата работы метода. Почему так?

Comment: @Bulson Да, я уже понял и исправил, теперь я просто передаю сюда Image, диспетчер же использую т.к. этот метод вызывается в другом потоке, но все равно проблема остается. Раньше я просто присваивал картинке которую я передаю результат этого метода
'item._Img = item.makeImage(item._Img, _mainw.Dispatcher);'

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь работать с UI-контролом из фонового потока — это невозможно.
UI-контрол принадлежит тому потоку, который её создал, и с ним можно работать только там, где создали.

Вы создаёте `Image` в UI-потоке, а пользуетесь им, видимо, в фоновом потоке, отсюда и проблема.

Если вы выносите создание `Image` в фоновый поток потому, что сама картинка (`image.Source`) требует большого времени для создания/распаковки, вам нужен другой подход. Вам нужно изменить код так, чтобы он создавал `Source` отдельно (в фоновом потоке), вызывал на нём `.Freeze()` (чтобы можно было пользоваться в основном потоке), передавал результат в UI-поток, и там создавал `Image`.

Если нет, то просто выполняйте нужную вам операцию в UI-потоке.